# remove blank lines not working in sed

Tags: sed

I have a file which has blank lines but the following sed command is not working:

```
sed -e 's/#.*//' -e '/^END/ d' -e '/^>/ d' -e '/^$*/ d' auto.txt > a.txt
```

It works but when I add the blank line thing it removes everything and i get empty file

### Sample

auto.txt

```
>#begin wildfire_pdm_x10
#wildfire_test server pdml x10 mode=PDM_MDHTASM clean_cache
proe_wfpdmo_wsabar_pdmactions+PDM_MDHTASM+wfpdmo_wsabar_pdmactions.txt@proe.wfpdmo_wsabar_pdmactions
END
#wildfire_test server pdml x10 mode=PDM_MDTTB clean_cache
proe_wfpdmo_wstbar_pdmactions+PDM_MDTTB+wfpdmo_wstbar_pdmactions.txt@proe.wfpdmo_wstbar_pdmactions
END
```

### output needed

a.txt

```
proe_wfpdmo_wsabar_pdmactions+PDM_MDHTASM+wfpdmo_wsabar_pdmactions.txt@proe.wfpdmo_wsabar_pdmactions

proe_wfpdmo_wstbar_pdmactions+PDM_MDTTB+wfpdmo_wstbar_pdmactions.txt@proe.wfpdmo_wstbar_pdmactions
proe_wfpdmo_pdm_matfnc_b+PDM_MTLFNC+wfpdmo_pdm_matfnc_b.txt@proe.wfpdmo_pdm_matfnc_b
proe_wfpdmo_proe_resparam+PDM_PARM+wfpdmo_proe_resparam.txt@proe.wfpdmo_proe_resparam
proe_wfpdmo_proe_restrparam+PDM_PARM+wfpdmo_proe_restrparam.txt@proe.wfpdmo_proe_restrparam
proe_wfpdmo_proe_restrparam_b+PDM_PARM+wfpdmo_proe_restrparam_b.txt@proe.wfpdmo_proe_restrparam_b
proe_wfpdmo_proe_restrparam_b+PDM_PARM+wfpdmo_proe_restrparam_b_2.txt@proe.wfpdmo_proe_restrparam_b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use awk

```
$ awk 'NF && !/^(>|END)/ && !/#.*/' file
```

Comment: Yes you can. But this doesn't tell you what is wrong with "the blank line thing" or show how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

This is removing all lines:

```
-e '/^$*/ d'
```

Remove the asterisk:

```
-e '/^$/d'
```

This will give you:

```
$ sed -e 's/#.*//' -e '/^END/ d' -e '/^>/ d' -e '/^$/ d' auto.txt
proe_wfpdmo_wsabar_pdmactions+PDM_MDHTASM+wfpdmo_wsabar_pdmactions.txt@proe.wfpdmo_wsabar_pdmactions
proe_wfpdmo_wstbar_pdmactions+PDM_MDTTB+wfpdmo_wstbar_pdmactions.txt@proe.wfpdmo_wstbar_pdmactions
```